# This section isn't available to yet. It was added from another device. You'll be able to use it when it syncs

Tags: sync, microsoft-onenote

I just got my surface 9 and wanted to try OneNote with my pen, but as soon as I got into the application it gave me the error "This section isn't avaible yet. It was added from another device. You'll be able to use it when it syncs." This is my first ever microsoft and I don't have another device where I used OneNote so I'm confused as to why it's saying it was added from another device.

Comment: That is just the wording of the notice.  I assume, eventually, the document synchronizes, and the notice goes away?

Comment: One Note can work on more than Windows and more than one device.  Did you add the section from your phone or like device?  The error you got cannot occur with a single device

Comment: As stated, the question is what is it syncing with - was this computer used by someone else before you got it?